# Встроенный отладчик VS2017 и утечки памяти

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Добрый день.

Пишу простой код:

```
int main(){
    int ret=0;
    char* ddd = new char[100];
    return ret;
}
```

Создаю debug проект в VS2017.
Запускаю проект в отладчике.
Все нормально завершается без всяких замечаний, хотя налицо утечка памяти.

Вопросы:

1. Разве встроенный отладчик VS2017 не ловит утечки памяти? Или надо где-то в настройках включить переключатель, чтобы встроенный отладчик VS2017 начал ловить утечки памяти?
2. Если встроенный отладчик VS2017 не ловит утечки памяти, то какой отладчик их ловит?
3. Когда-то я работал на древнем Borland C++ Builder 6.0, так на его отладчике такие утечки памяти прекрасно ловились. А тут новейшая IDE от ведущего производителя и утечка памяти не ловится.

Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, вас заинтересует memory debugger (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У майкрософта для дампа утечек есть своя либа (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx).

По умолчанию, обычное консольное приложение вам ничего не покажет.

Чтобы увидеть утечки надо добавить пару строк:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h> 

int main() 
{
    int ret = 0;
    char* ddd = new char[100];

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); 
    return ret;
}
```

И видим ожидаемый вывод:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{74} normal block at 0x03326468, 100 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

Comment: Лучше `_CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);` вместо `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); ` . Второй вариант неверно выводит память аллоцированную в конструкторах глобальных объектов как утечки.

Comment: Действительно, _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); работает и даже ловит утечки. Спасибо. При рефакторинге кода потерялся virtual в деструкторе базового класса и появились утечки памяти. И этот механизм поймал их.

Answer (score 0):

Для виндовсов есть программы, которые отслеживают утечки и прочие грязные штучки, типа использования неинициализированных переменных, без необходимости помещать что-то дополнительное в код. В основном, это проприетарные изделия, но есть и более доступные и бесплатные.

Возможно, Вас заинтересует [обсуждение вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows), близкого Вашему, на stackoverflow.com